# How to Group n-Rows in single Field (like GROUP_CONCAT in MYSQL)

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server-ce

I am using SQL Server Compact edition in my C# application to store the data. For my Datagrid I need to display the TITLE and the TAGS (separated with `,`) which belong to it in a single row.

In MySQL there is a `GROUP_CONCAT()` function which leads to my desired result. Unfortunately SQL Server CE doesn't have such functionality, so I hope that somebody here has a workaround/solution for this problem.

```
Article                     ArticleTags                Tags 
+-------------+----------+  +------------+----------+  +----------+---------+
+ ARTICLE_ID  + TITLE    +  + ARTICLE_ID + TAG_ID   +  + TAG_ID   + Name    +
+-------------+----------+  +------------+----------+  +----------+---------+
+ 1           + A        +  + 1          + 20       +  + 20       + Sport   +
+ 2           + B        +  + 1          + 21       +  + 21       + Web     +
+ 3           + C        +  + 1          + 22       +  + 22       + Nature  +
+-------------+----------+  + 3          + 23       +  + 23       + Girls   +
                            +------------+----------+  +----------+---------+
```

I need the following result:

```
+------------+----------------------+
+ TITLE      + TAGS                 +
+------------+----------------------+
+ A          + Sport, Web, Nature   +
+ B          +                      +
+ C          + Girls                +
+------------+----------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Try  this:

```
SELECT a.title, tags.tagNames
FROM (
    SELECT t.article_ID article_ID, 
      STUFF(
             (SELECT ', ' + p.name 
              FROM articletags t2
                inner join tags p on (t2.tag_id=p.tag_id)
              WHERE t.article_ID = t2.article_ID
              FOR XML PATH (''))
              , 1, 2, '')  AS tagNames
    FROM articletags t
    GROUP BY article_id) tags
    right JOIN article a on (tags.article_id = a.article_id)
```

Comment: Unfortunately I get an error with this sql. Visual Studio says that derived table isnt supported.

Comment: Isn§t there any chance to use SQL Express instead of Compact Edition? Any other solution that comes to my mind is also requires at least Express Edition.